# Parity of Large Numbers: Modulo Operator vs. Bitwise Operator

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, modulo, modulus

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889838/is-bitwise-operation-faster-than-modulo-reminder-operator-in-java), but it doesn't seem to fully answer the question.

For large numbers, would using a bitwise-and operation, `n & 1 == 0`, be more efficient for determining the parity of a number (whether it is even or odd) than using the modulo operator, `n % 2 == 0`?

With Java 9 on its way in just a few months, we'll be given access to new micro-benchmarking tools which could possibly provide a definite answer to this question.

I imagine there would be a benefit, however I wouldn't know if it would be noticeable.

My current assumption also leads me to believe that the compiler might optimize the modulo operator to use the bitwise-and operator instead, but I'm curious if that's true.

Comment: Use whatever is easier to understand in the current situation. Even if there is a difference (which I don't think - both operations use the same time on modern CPUs), it would be negligible.

Comment: There might be a difference, depending on specific optimizations. If the compiler has no specific pattern for `n % 2 == 0` and relies only on optimizing `n % 2`, it cannot rewrite it to `n & 1` in that case. It would still not be an actual division of course, so not *that* slow. But it can reasonably be slower than `n & 1`. I also don't think there's ever a legitimate reason to write `n % 2 == 0` because it is never clearer than `n & 1 == 0`.